# Quora's HTML doesn't show schema.org, but google shows them in the question/answer section, how?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, microdata, json-ld, googlebot

I'm making a scraper to read question / answer data for students that supports RDFa, Json LD, and Microdata, but Quora confuses me. *I need to understand how it's read so that I can read it in my HTML question / answer scraper for situations like this.*

In a google search, I see a QA block, but if I go to the URL https://www.quora.com/What-happens-when-sodium-chloride-and-water-is-heated-to-dry I don't see any evidence of JSON LD, RDFa or Microdata. **How is google reading quora's question / answer information?**

Possible reasons I can think of:

- They only show that data to search engine user-agents. So perhaps I should change the user-agent to a scraper when requesting the page.
- Google figured it out on its own. This means I need to create some NLP solution to get the information.
- Key words that identify the page as question / answer.
- Google does something special for big Q/A sites like quora (but stack overflow has schema.org, so I don't think this is true).

PS: Even google doesn't show support for other formats: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/qapage

[image]

Comment: This isn't a programming question, so it isn't on-topic here either.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I'm trying to identify the question / answer information inside the HTML, and determine what I need to do in order to find the QA information from Quora or similar situations. AKA do I need to change the `user-agent` ? Do I have to make a smart reader, etc. I might not have successfully communicated that, but it is a programming question. I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: To make this an on-topic programming question, you would need to post the code that you have written and ask about a problem with it.

Comment: Google reads this page's structured data as rich results - https://search.google.com/test/rich-results/result/r%2Fq-and-a?id=3aNOu3qg7TnhPNz-_xKuuQ

Comment: @nikant25 thank you for that, that proves there is schema

Comment: The schema is there. However, the fact that it is not captured by the Schema testing tool (  
https://validator.schema.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quora.com%2FWhat-happens-when-sodium-chloride-and-water-is-heated-to-dry ) is an alarm. This can interfere with parsing or skew the results.

Comment: @nikant25 that was the issue I was running into, they appear to only show the schema to search engine user agents

Comment: Schema shows for me most test results of separate websites. I don't think the problem is with the tool. It is also a former Google structured data testing tool that was created for the purpose of testing users' websites. This tool was transferred to the Schema not very long ago and they could hardly spoil much there.

Comment: I totally agree, this is definitely just from how Quora set up their page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's shown only to search engine user agents, use `Googlebot`.

@nikrant25 showed the schema does indeed exist: https://search.google.com/test/rich-results/result/r%2Fq-and-a?id=3aNOu3qg7TnhPNz-_xKuuQ . So I decided to do a scrape with `Googlebot` as the useragent and the schema showed up.